# scala generics and inheritance

Tags: scala, generics

I have an issue with the following hierarchy in scala:

```
class ScalaGenericTest {
  def getValue[A, B <: Abstract[A]](clazz: B): A = clazz.a

  def call: String = {
    val sub: Subclass = new Subclass
    getValue(sub)
  }
}

class Subclass extends Abstract[String] {
  def a: String = "STRING"
}

abstract class Abstract[A] {
  def a: A
}
```

The compiler doesn't seem to be able to bind the generic parameter A in the call to the getValue function -- I think it should be able to infer this from the definition of Subclass. The compile error is as follows:

> inferred type arguments [Nothing,Subclass] do not conform to method getValue's type parameter bounds [A,B <: Abstract[A]]

It works if I explicitly pass the generic type arguments to the method, i.e. `getValue[String,Subclass](sub)` but surely the compiler should be able to infer this?

The same hierarchy works fine in Java:

```
public class JavaGenericTest {

    public  <T,U extends Abstract<T>> T getValue(U subclass) {
         return subclass.getT();
    }

    public String call(){
        Subclass sub = new Subclass();
        return getValue(sub);
    }

    private static class Subclass extends Abstract<String> {
         String getT(){
            return "STRING";
        }
    }

    private static abstract class Abstract<T> {
        abstract T getT();
    }
}
```

I'm pretty new to Scala so there's probably some subtlety that I'm missing.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a limitation in Scala's type inference. The issue is described in [SI-2272](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2272) (the example there uses implicits, but the same error occurs when using it explicitly). It's been closed as **won't fix**.

In that issue, Adriaan Moors advises to avoid constraints that have type variables on both sides. ie. `B <: Abstract[A]`. An easy work-around would be to avoid the second type parameter altogether.

```
def getValue[A](clazz: Abstract[A]): A = clazz.a

scala> val sub = new Subclass
sub: Subclass = Subclass@585cbda6

scala> getValue(sub)
res11: String = STRING
```

Additionally, Adriaan also provided a way of using an implicit `<:<` as another work around. To put it in the context of your example, it would look like:

```
def getValue[A, B](b: B)(implicit ev: B <:< Abstract[A]): B = b.a
```

Where an instance of `<:<` is provided implicitly through [Predef](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef$$$less$colon$less).

Comment: You can also use an implicit view on the generic parameter with `B <% Abstract[A]`.  I think that might be deprecated, but the implicit argument it produces is sufficient evidence for the type inference.

Comment: Great answer. I did consider the implicit argument approach but couldn't see a good reason why the original didn't work. View bounds using <% have definitely been deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

I have same problem at one time too. And created large implicit evidence hack to overcome. Afterwards I accidentally look into scala collection api docs and found a solution: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.collection.generic.GenericTraversableTemplate

```
class ScalaGenericTest {
  def getValue[A, B[X] <: Abstract[X]](clazz: B[A]): A = clazz.a

  def call: String = {
    val sub: Subclass = new Subclass
    getValue(sub)
  }
}

class Subclass extends Abstract[String] {
  def a: String = "STRING"
}

abstract class Abstract[A] {
  def a: A
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As addition to Justin's and m-z's answers, another way to make similar declaration keeping two type parameters:

```
def getValue[A, B](clazz: B)(implicit evidence: B <:< Abstract[A]): A = clazz.a
```